# Logstash add an event to an existing document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I already have a document in Elasticsearch with id (let's say `1`). I need to configure Logstash so that an event with the same id gets inserted into Elasticsearch.

Example document where an ID already exists:

```json
{
  "name": "abc"
}
```

Logstash event:

```json
{
  "address": "new york",
  "mobile no": "xxx"
}
```

The final result in Elasticsearch:

```json
{
  "name": "abc",
  "address": "new york",
  "mobile no": "xxx"
}
```

I tried using update script in output plugin:

```
elasticsearch {
    action => "update"
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "details"
    scripted_upsert => true
    document_id => "%{id}"
    script => "ctx._source.name = params.event.get('name')"
}
```

This allows me to add each field (`name`, `address`, etc) but I need to insert the entire json event without specifying each field. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's way easier than you think ;)

Elasticsearch supports upserting: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-doc_as_upsert

So combining `action => update` together with `doc_as_upsert => true` should do the job:

```
elasticsearch {
    action => "update"
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "details"
    doc_as_upsert => true
    document_id => "%{id}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :) maybe i was overthinking stuff